# Replace row value with NaN if particular word is present - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, data-cleaning

I am on the process of cleaning a dataframe, and I want to check if there are any values from a list of words in a dataframe. If it is present, the value should be replaced by NA values. For example,

My dataframe is like.

```
p['title']

1                                             Forest
2                                            [VIDEO_TITLE]
3                                            [VIDEO_TITLE]
4                                            [VIDEO_TITLE]
5                                [${title}url=${videourl}]


p.dtypes
title    object
dtype: object
```

and

```
c= ('${title}', '[VIDEO_TITLE]')
```

Since the rows 2,3,4,5 have the words in c, I want that to be replaced by NA values.

I'm trying the following,

```
p['title'].replace('|'.join(c),np.NAN,regex=True).fillna('NA')
```

This one runs without error, but I am getting the same input as output. There are no changes at all.

My next try is,

```
p['title'].apply(lambda x: 'NA' if any(s in x for s in c) else x)
```

which is throwing an error,

> TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

I am trying several other things without much success. I am not sure what mistake I am doing.

My ideal output would be,

```
p['title']

1     Forest
2        NA
3        NA
4        NA
5        NA
```

Can anybody help me in solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `loc` to set them as `'NA'`.  Since your values are sometimes inside a list, first they need to be extracted from the list.  The second line extracts the first string from the list, if it's in a list.  The third line checks for a match.

```
c = ('${title}', 'VIDEO_TITLE')
string_check = p['title'].map(lambda x: x if not isinstance(x, list) else x[0])
string_check = string_check.map(lambda s: any(c_str in s for c_str in c))
p.loc[string_check, 'title'] = 'NA'
```

Depending on what you're doing, you may want to consider setting the values to `numpy.nan` instead of the string `'NA'`.  This is the usual way pandas handles null values and there's a lot of functionality already built around this.

Comment: I tried this previously. I am getting "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' " error. Not sure what I should do to correct this

Comment: Even for "p['title'].isin(c)" I am getting this error.

Comment: Oh, so is `[VIDEO_TITLE]` actually a list containing a string, and not just a string?  Give me a minute for a fix.

Comment: For me the requirement is , it is a string. I am not sure whether I have not initiated properly or not.

Comment: I get the same error as you if I initialize the bracketed values as lists containing a string, i.e. `['VIDEO_Title']`.

Comment: Actually I tried the answer given below by initializing restricted variable. Still I am getting the same error. I think the problem may be due to p['title'].

Comment: I've removed the braces and tried to have a,b,c alone to see if it is working. Still I am getting the same error. Can we see whether there is any problem with p['title'] ?

Comment: Now only got to know a point. The dataframe column contains a series of lists. Every value is between [ ].

Comment: I've edited the answer to deal with a string inside of a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ('a','b','c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c')})
>>> restricted = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> df[df['A'].isin(restricted)] = np.NAN
>>> df
 A
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  NaN
3    d
4  NaN
5  NaN
```

Comment: I am getting the same error as said for the previous answer. "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: Try to set r before each element of restricted list restricted = [r'a', r'b', r'c']

Comment: for me the problem is with df['A'] here. When I tried, df['A'].dtypes it shows dtype('O'). Not sure what is happening.

Comment: Your example is working well for me. My dataframe is only not working.

Comment: Does title column contains strings or lists ?

Comment: Every value is like between [ ] . So is that a column of lists?

Comment: So if it list, how do you want compare c= ('${title}', '[VIDEO_TITLE]') and list ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I converted the lists to str and it seems to work now. one last request. This isin function removes it only when it exactly matches. I want it to remove even if some part of p['title'] contains words from restricted. Can we change this ?

Comment: I am not sure isin accept regular expressions, but you can try something like this: c= (r'\*${title}\*', r'\*[VIDEO_TITLE]\*'), where * means everything